# insert update values using triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need your assistance here.

I have two tables `MasterEntries` and `Awardlist`. `MasterEntries` have results of rankings eg.1,2,3,4,5,6 from some events. I want to use a T-SQL trigger to select and insert the rankings from `MasterEntries` **NAMELY** 1,2,3 and insert it in a similar column (ranked) in the `AwardList` table **ONLY WHEN** the count of records relating to a respective event reaches 6.

Here are my table structures:

`MasterEntries` table

```
[EntryID]              INT           IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CompetitiveEventCode] NVARCHAR(5)   NULL,
[CompetitiveEventName] NVARCHAR(40)  NULL,
[CategoryDescription]  NVARCHAR(25)  NULL,
[YearOfEvent]          NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
[CompetitorID]         INT           NOT NULL,
[FirstName]            NVARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[LastName]             NVARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[Institution]          NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
[ParishName]           NVARCHAR(15)  NULL,
[Region]               NVARCHAR(12)  NULL,
[Participated]         NVARCHAR(3)   NULL,
[AccumulatedMarks]     DECIMAL(5, 2) NULL,
[AverageMark]          DECIMAL(5, 2) NULL,
[Ranked]               INT           NULL,
[PointsEarned]         INT           NULL,
[AwardPlacing]         CHAR(4)       NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_MasterEntries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EntryID] ASC)
```

`Awardlist` table

```
[AwardID]              INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[CompetitiveEventName] NVARCHAR(40)  NULL,
[CategoryDescription]  NVARCHAR(255) NULL,
[FirstName]            NVARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[LastName]             NVARCHAR(20)  NULL,
[Institution]          NVARCHAR(50)  NULL,
[ParishName]           NVARCHAR(15)  NULL,
[Region]               NVARCHAR(12)  NULL,
[AverageMark]          DECIMAL(5, 2) NULL,
[Ranked]               INT           NULL,
[AwardPlacing]         CHAR(4)       NULL, 
[CompetitiveEventCode] NVARCHAR(5)   NULL
```

I tried the following queries

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Award_list_FROM_MasterEntries
ON MasterEntries
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @rankedcount INT,
            @CompetitiveEventCode NVARCHAR(5), 
            @CompetitiveEventName NVARCHAR(40),
            @CategoryDescription NVARCHAR(25), 
            @FirstName NVARCHAR(2), 
            @LastName NVARCHAR(25), 
            @ParishName NVARCHAR(15),  
            @Region NVARCHAR(12), 
            @Institution NVARCHAR(50),  
            @AverageMark INT,
            @Ranked INT, 
            @AwardPlacing NVARCHAR(4)

    SELECT @rankedcount = Count(CompetitiveEventCode)
    FROM MasterEntries
    WHERE CompetitiveEventCode = 'AGPRO' 
      AND Ranked = 1 AND Ranked = 2 And Ranked = 3;

    IF @rankedcount = 6
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AwardList(CompetitiveEventCode, CompetitiveEventName, CategoryDescription, FirstName, LastName, ParishName,
                              Region, Institution, AverageMark, Ranked, AwardPlacing)
        VALUES (@CompetitiveEventCode, @CompetitiveEventName, @CategoryDescription, @FirstName, @LastName, @ParishName,
                @Region, @Institution, @AverageMark, @Ranked, @AwardPlacing);

    END;
```

AND also

```
CREATE TRIGGER Insert_Award_list_INTO_AWARDStesting2
ON MasterEntries
AFTER INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @rankedcount INT

    SELECT @rankedcount = Count(CompetitiveEventCode)
    FROM MasterEntries
    WHERE CompetitiveEventCode = 'AGPRO' 
      AND Ranked = 1 AND Ranked = 2 And Ranked = 3;

    IF @rankedcount = 6
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO AwardList(CompetitiveEventName, CategoryDescription, FirstName, LastName, ParishName,
                              Region, Institution, AverageMark, Ranked, AwardPlacing)
            SELECT  
                me.CompetitiveEventName,me.CategoryDescription, me.FirstName, me.LastName, me.ParishName, 
                me.Region, me.Institution, me.AverageMark, me.Ranked, me.AwardPlacing 
            FROM 
                MasterEntries me
            LEFT JOIN
                AwardList al ON me.Institution = al.Institution
    END
```

Please help me solve this as none of the above triggers is giving me the results, Please

Comment: `WHERE CompetitiveEventCode = 'AGPRO' AND Ranked = 1 AND Ranked = 2 And Ranked = 3;` How can Ranking be 1 AND 2 AND 3 at the same time ?

Comment: Your trigger does not reference inserted or deleted virtual tables. This is a big red flag that something is not right in your trigger.

Comment: You have a left join you don't even use.  This has a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this piece of code

```
WHERE CompetitiveEventCode = 'AGPRO' AND Ranked = 1 AND Ranked = 2 And Ranked = 3;
```

Is it possible to have same CompetitiveEventCode(i.e.'AGPRO') in Ranks 1,2 and 3 at the same time?
According to the condition **@rankedcount** will be counted when all the conditions satisfied.

Comment: there are far more problems with both queries than just this part